# Exceptions to the rule of washing ones hands in the morning

Tags: halacha, contemporary-halacha

The Rosh Brachot 9:23 says "one needs to clean one's hands for davening and at night when sleeping one's hands might touch a dirty area". Rashba Tshuvah 1:191 says "because a person is recreated each day and the the bracha was established like brachot hashachar".Zohar Vayeshev 184b cited by Bet Yosef 4:8 says "that the negative spirit is a result of the element of death that descends upon a person who sleeps".

**Is there any exception to this rule listed cited by Poskim?**

Please cite sources, thank you.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you expect there might be an exception?

Comment: Isn't there always lol @Alex

Comment: Define “exceptions.” Do you mean unusual cases like “I didn’t sleep last night“ or “I slept with gloves on” or “I woke from a coma” or something like that? Or do you mean “I slept perfectly normally last night but want to know if any theoretical external factors might apply to exempt me”?

Comment: @donieif the latter